# Pass parameters from $get promise response to $scope

Tags: angularjs

I do a ajax (get) request and obtain a promise with json data in a angular "jobList" service.

Then I update the scope with the obtained data. But my problem is that to update a scope variable 'X' I need to create a function per variable "readX" (see bellow).

Is there a way to add parameters, like in the last function in the following code?

```
app.controller("JobListController", ['$scope', '$timeout', 'jobList',
    function ($scope, $timeout, jobList) {
        var readList = function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.list = response;
                    $scope.$apply();
                });
            }
        };
        var readFamilies = function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.allFamilies = response;
                    $scope.$apply();
                });
            }
        };
        var readRegions = function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.allRegions = response;
                    $scope.$apply();
                });
            }
        };
        // !!! ----- HERE ------------- !!!
        var readSomething = function (response, something) {
            if (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope[something] = response;
                    $scope.$apply();
                });
            }
        };

        jobList.get().then(readList);
        jobList.getAll("allFamilies").then(readFamilies);
        jobList.getAll("allRegions").then(readRegions);
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start you could simplify those callback functions: provided the callback happens inside angular (and it you're using `$http` it will) you don't need the `$timeout` call nor the `$scope.$apply()` call. Also you should write your service to only succeed if it returns data, reject the promise if it fail;s and that way you don't need the `if` So each callback could just be the assignment.

If you are making multiple calls that return promises, can you collapse the calls together?

```
$q.all([jobList.get(), jobList.getAll("allFamilies"), jobList.getAll("allRegions")])
.then(([list, families, regions]) => {
    $scope.list = list;
    $scope.allFamilies = families;
    $scope.allRegions = regions;
});
```

I used es6 syntax here: it's well worth setting up your build chain to use something like babeljs so you can use the shorthand notation for simple callbacks.

If you really want to make the calls separately (they still evaluate in parallel) you can write a factory to generate the callbacks:

```
function assignToScope(name) {
    return success;

    function success(data) {
        $scope[name] = data;
    }
}
jobList.get().then(assignToScope('list'));
jobList.getAll("allFamilies").then(assignToScope('allFamilies'));
jobList.getAll("allRegions").then(assignToScope('allRegions'));
```

Answer (score 1):

you could save the required property in a `scope` variable, before getting the data.

Something like this:

```
$scope.property = "list";
jobList.get().then(readSomething);
```

and your function would now become:

```
var readSomething = function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope[$scope.property] = response;
                    $scope.$apply();
                });
            }
        };
```

P.S:

I guess you can also use closures to do something like this:

```
var readSomething = function (something) {
            return function(response){
                if (response) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $scope[something] = response;
                        $scope.$apply();
                    });
                }
           }
        };
```

Comment: so need to do 2 calls foreach function, set the variable, then call the function...

Comment: yeah, otherwise you can take a look at the closure way, i have edited my answer

Comment: readSomething("list") , the response will be passed automatically to the inner function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    jobList.get().then(function (response) {
    readSomething(response);
    });
```

And function readSomething can have response only as in input.